# Enviar dados junto com evento

Tags: jquery

Conforme me aventuro pelo jQuery algumas dúvidas e problemas surgem no meio do caminho, uma delas é: é possível enviar um dado através de um evento acionado por outro evento? Algo como isso:

**jQuery**

```
$(".seletor1").on("click", function(){
    $(".seletor2").trigger("click", dados);
});
//
$(".seletor2").on("click", function(dados){
    alert(dados);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim podes. Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/XBDrh/

```
$(".seletor1").on("click", function(){
    console.log('Clicado!');
    $(".seletor2").trigger("click", {animal: 'gato'});
});
//
$(".seletor2").on("click", function(evento, animais){
    alert(evento.type);
    alert(animais.animal);
});
```

Olhando para a documentação do jQuery a syntax esperada é:

> #### .trigger( tipoEvento [, parametrosExtra] )
>
> ***tipoEvento***
>   **Typo:** String
>   **Descrição**: Uma string contento o nome do evento. Por exemplo 'click' ou 'submit'
>
> ***parametrosExtra***
>   **Typo:** Array or Objeto
>   **Descrição**: Parametros adicionais a passar com o evento.

---

Se quiser misturar esse click handler com um click verdadeiro pode criar um `if` para verificar se foi passado o objeto extra. Sugestão:

```
$(".seletor2").on("click", function (evento, animais) {

    if (!animais) {
        alert("Clicou no seletor2");
        return false;
    }

    switch (animais.animal) {
        case 'gato':
            alert("Clicou no seletor1");
            break;
        case 'cao':
            alert("Clicou no seletor1");
            break;
        case 'elefante':
            alert("Clicou no seletor1");
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: No caso `animal` é como se fosse um endereço para `'gato'`? Só não entendi a necessidade do `alert(evento.type);`.

Comment: @Patrick, evento é um objeto. Eu coloquei `evento.type` porque essa propriedade é por padrão o nome do evento, e é só para confirmar que é o nome certo. O segundo parametro é também um objeto cuja chave é "animal" e o valor é "gato".

Comment: @Patrick, já agora dá uma olhada no google a `console.log()`, bem melhor que o `alert()` e dá para ver objetos, coisa que o alert não dá.

Comment: @Patrick, pode colocar o código que está a usar no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XBDrh/1/ para eu ver

Comment: @Patrick o erro está correto, pode explicar melhor o que quer fazer? pois quando clica no `seletor2` esse parametro `animais` não existe pois o `trigger` só é disparado quando carrega no `seletor1`

Comment: Então, minha intenção era dizer: "se o usuário clicar diretamente no `seletor2`, vá para o `default` e faça X, mas se ele clicar no `seletor1`, vá para `'gato'` e faça Y. Ao meu ver, *undefined* jogaria para o `default`.

Comment: @Patrick, ok, assim já percebo melhor o que quer. Quantas opções vai ter? se forem muitas eu sugeria algo assim: __http://jsfiddle.net/7euUL/1/__ (de qualquer maneira o problema é que o `animais` não está defenido no caso do clic no seletor2, e por isso ele dá erro quando quer saber o valor de `animais.animal`.

Comment: @Patrick ótimo que funcionou! Boa ideia de juntar à resposta, fiz isso agora. Amanhã passo por aqui e limpo os comentários também.